# Jquery add class based on a href

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a class based on the table cell starting with a particular a href.

This is the HTML:

```
  <tr class="odd">
    <td class=" sorting_1">
      <a href="/workorders/1">13-10000</a>
    </td>
```

I thought this would work, but it doesn't:

```
$('a[href$^="/workorders/"]').addClass("boldnowrap");
```

I'm actually using coffeescript:

```
$('a[href$^="/workorders/"]').addClass "boldnowrap"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why is there a `$` in there? If you remove that, then it should work; provided the `href` is what you think it is.

Comment: You have too many modifiers in there. `^` for start of string, `$` for end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[href$^="..."]` part is invalid selector.

You're looking for one of these, I think:

```
$('a[href^="/workorders/"]').addClass("boldnowrap");
$('a[href*="/workorders/"]').addClass("boldnowrap");
```

Beware that the second one will match everytime `/workorders/` is found in your `href`, what *may not* be what you want.

Comment: I think that what's actually needed is: `a[href*="/workorders/"]`

So it would work for hrefs like ".../workorders/..."

Comment: One more questions.  The script works - if I type it into the browser console.  But, it's not working in my Rails app.  I think because the table I'm trying to execute against is a jquery dataTable.  So, I'm guessing that this script must run after the dataTable is done. How do I ensure this script runs last?

Comment: Your plugin probably have a event like `created`, `rendered`, or something like this. If so, place the call inside this event.

Comment: Figured out a way with your help= `   fnDrawCallback: (oSettings) ->
      $('a[href*="/workorders/"]').parent('td').addClass "strongnowrap"`